# Errors while installing ros-indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting this error while trying to install Ros indigo:

```
Unpacking ros-indigo-desktop-full (1.1.6-0trusty-20181117-082021-0800) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.10-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-catkin-pkg_0.4.10-100_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro-modules_0.7.2-1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-rosdistro_0.7.2-100_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm installing this on a guest ubuntu 14.04 in virtualbox. All these packages seem to be related to python but I don't know how exactly to solve this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314721/errors-while-installing-ros-indigo-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [paul_shuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37881/paul_shuvo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2019-02-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see whether #q299091 covers this.

> All these packages seem to be related to python [..]

It's not really about Python, that's just a coincidence. It's the format these pkg use.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paul_shuvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/37881/paul_shuvo/) on 2019-02-05**:
Yes, running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dpkg` comands did the trick.